# Systematic Design in DrRacket

Tags: racket

Complete the design of a function called pyramid that takes a natural
number n and an image, and constructs an n-tall, n-wide pyramid of
copies of that image. I am trying to design HtDF but i am facing a difficulty on how stack the images vertically in DrRacket. Looking for assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the functions `below` and `above`.

See  http://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpimage.html?q=2htdp#%28def._%28%28lib._2htdp%2Fimage..rkt%29._above%29%29

Answer (score -1):

I used "above" and "beside"

**above:** Constructs an image by placing all of the argument images in a vertical row, aligned along their centers.

**beside:** Constructs an image by placing all of the argument images in a horizontal row, aligned along their centers

(require 2htdp/image)

...

;;=======
;;Function...
;;...
(check-expect...
(check-expect...
(check-expect...

**(above IMAGE
(beside IMAGE IMAGE)
(beside IMAGE IMAGE IMAGE))**